# Debug Vbscripts using mono

Tags: ubuntu, vbscript, mono

I know how to debug vbscripts using Visual Studio on windows.I just want to know how to debug vbscripts on ubuntu using mono?

Debugging vbscript using visual studio:-

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/how-to-debugg-vbscript-files-or-vbs.html

Comment: VBScript is a Windows only technology http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript. I don't know how you get it running on Ubuntu/Mono and are in need of debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the option `//x` instructs the interpreter (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`) to launch the script in a debugger. If several debuggers are installed you're prompted to chose one. However, regardless of the debugger you still need the interpreter, which - as far as I am aware - is not available for Linux.

Using `//d` in conjunction with `//x` is futile, BTW. `//d` would cause the interpreter to launch a debugger when the script encounters an error during normal execution. `//x` launches the debugger right away, so the script is already running in the debugger when a condition arises that would trigger debugging.